# setAttribute and text

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to change the colour of a text with setAttribute?
This piece of code does what I asked it to do, it prints the text

```
"<font color=\"08870e\">Condition true</font>"
```

However I want it to recognize that I'm adding "font" container.

This is the code.

```
    if(condition) {
        $("status").set("text", "<font color=\"08870e\">Condition true</font>");
    }
else
    {
        $("status").set("text", "<font color=\"03i9ie\">Condition false</font>");
    }
if(condition2) 
{
        $("status2").set("text", "Condition 2 is true");
    }
else
    {
        $("status2").set("text", "Condition 2 is false");
```

By the way, it's in the function which is called every 15 seconds therefore other methods aren't preferred.

**Update:** `$ = document.getElementById`

Comment: jQuery doesn't appear to have a `set` method. I'm guessing it is coming from an unspecified plug-in. What you can achieve with it will depend on that plug-in. (But the `<font>` element is deprecated and `03i9ie` is not a colour anyway)

Comment: And how could that code lead to the word Paranoid being printed? It doesn't appear anywhere in the code!

Comment: @Quentin I did not set the "jquery" tag, probably the system did automatically. Anyhow, the $ is Javascript original, representing document.getElementById(). http://goo.gl/zOj2W

Comment: Err… looking at the history, that was set by @Mrchief. This is why I [hate the dollar function](http://blog.dorward.me.uk/2009/02/19/the-dollar-function-must-die.html). There is no `set` method for HTMLElementNodes either though.

Comment: @Quentin, it's my mistake; while I was editing, I had some sensitive information in the script, a password (somewhere else, not "Paranoid"). I then edited the whole code for a template, rather my personal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need somthing like this:

```
$("status").text("Condition is true").css("color", "green");
$("status").text("Condition is false").css("color", "red"); // or .css("color", "#ff0000");
```

instead of named colors like `"red"`, you can use hex rgb values `"#ff0000"`

**Update:** If `$ = document.getElementById` then here's a JS way:

```
$("status").innerText = "Condition is false";  // .textContent for anything other than IE < 9 and non IE browsers.
$("status").style.color = "#ff0000";
```

Apologies for assuming $ was part of jQuery. Removed the tag jQuery from here and edited the question.

Comment: @Add `.textContent` works in the other browsers (and IE9 at least)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for reminding. Too much IE exposure has spoilt my memory!